# Document Updates - Do updates with no changes still cost 1 write?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Do document updates, where the update from a client, has no difference with the Firestore server copy still cost in terms of number of writes?

Also would a cloud function that is listening for updates also be invoked?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Cloud Firestore Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing) documentation, each `set()` or `update()` operation will count as a write. In this case, you will still be charged with the cost of 1 write when called with new changes or not.

Answer (score 1):

Document updates all incur billing for a write.  But Cloud Functions and realtime listeners will not be invoked if data doesn't actually change in the document.  The only situation where I suspect a listener might be invoked is if the client itself attempts to make an update to the same document it's listening to, but I'm not sure about that.