# Firestore billing for writes that have no effect

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, billing

Im trying to find out how firebase is billing write operations. In the billings documentation I could not find a clear definition of when a write is counted. Lets say I run a `set` query with the exact same data of the original documen, such that the document won't be affected, will this be billed as a write operation?

When I run my query with the console open nothing happens, and i was just wondering if these writes do also count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write data, the server doesn't check if the data you write is the same as what already exist. Instead: it writes the data you provide. Hence: writing the same data is still counted as a write operation.

I find it easiest to understand the billing for Firestore by thinking of it as reads from/writes to a disk. When you tell a disk to write a file, it writes that file.

Comment: FYI this is a dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57960599/document-updates-do-updates-with-no-changes-still-cost-1-write